# CSS comments cause weird effects

Tags: css, comments

Can anyone explain why using comments like this  in css cause really weird effects SOMETIMES?

---

This works fine

```
/*  ------------------------------  */
/*  some text here                  */
/*  ------------------------------  */
```

---

This appear to work fine too until I reload a page and then the page is all messed up in firefox and in chrome if I use any comments like this in css

```
<!-- sometext here -->
```

Comment: Why is it so hard to use search first and then ask question?

http://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_syntax.asp

Comment: @GaVra Hard? I have been using the wrong method for comments for a long time, which means I was not aware I was doing it wrong. It's hard to search for something when you don't know it is even wrong. thanks for the down vote and the negative comment though, hope it helped your ego.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For CSS files.

```
<!-- -->
```

Is not a comment syntax.

Comment: oh that would explain a lot then, I just assumed there was a few different ways of doing it, so this style is for html?

Comment: Right, that comment format is for HTML and XML (both derived from SGML). In general, every language will have its own comment format(s), and it's wise to be sure that you're using a correct one.

Answer (score 3):

Why are you using XML-like comment blocks in CSS?  Your first form (`/* comment */`) is the only one supported in CSS.